# PyQt6 QMdiArea behaves weird when moving SubWindow

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt6, qt6

I've started developing a new application with PyQt6.
After creating a new container with QMdiArea, I drew a logo on it.

This my code

```py
class MDIArea(QMdiArea):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.logo_pixmap = QPixmap('assets/logo.png')

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self.viewport())
        
        pos_x = int((self.width() - self.logo_pixmap.width()) / 2)
        pos_y = int((self.height() - self.logo_pixmap.height()) / 2)

        painter.drawPixmap(
            pos_x, pos_y,
            self.logo_pixmap.width(), self.logo_pixmap.height(),
            self.logo_pixmap)

        painter.end()
```

I created a sub-window within the main window class for testing, but it behaves a little strange

MainWindow class

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Test')

        self.mdi = MDIArea(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)

        sub_window = SubWindow(self)
        sub_window.setWidget(QTextEdit())
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub_window)

        self.show()
```

[image]

If I remove the drawing function it works properly

Comment: Try adding `super().paintEvent(event)` at the top of `MDIArea.paintEvent`.  Otherwise the background never gets cleared/redrawn.

Comment: It's work! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By default QMdiArea draws its background using its [`background`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html#background-prop) property, which is done within its `paintEvent()`. Since you're overriding it, there's nothing to draw, so whatever appears inside the area becomes *buffered* on the paint surface.

If you want to keep the background, also call the base implementation, which will draw the default background as a "base" for your image:

```py
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        painter = QPainter(self.viewport())
        ...
```

Or, alternatively, just fill the whole rectangle with either the existing background brush, or your custom color:

```py
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self.viewport())
        painter.fillRect(self.viewport().rect(), QColor('skyblue'))
        ...
```

<sup>Note: there's no need to call the painter's `end()`, since it's implicit when it's destroyed due to garbage collection at the end of `paintEvent()`.</sup>

Also, if you only want a centered logo, you may consider to just use a centered QLabel inside the viewport:

```py
class MDIArea(QMdiArea):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        bgd = QLabel()
        bgd.setPixmap(QPixmap('assets/logo.png'))
        QVBoxLayout(self.viewport()).addWidget(
            bgd, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
```